# What should I do about "Possible compare of value type with 'null'"?

Tags: c#

While writing this method for a custom NUnit Constraint.

```
    private void AddMatchFailure<TExpected, TActual>(string failureName, TExpected expected, TActual actual)
    {
        _matchFailures.Add(
            String.Format(MatchFailureFormat, failureName,
            (expected == null) ? "null" : expected.ToString(),
            (actual == null) ? "null" : actual.ToString()));
    }
```

Resharper warns that `expected` and `actual` might be `ValueType` objects.

```
e.g. TExpected is DateTime
   expected == null;//  but DateTime is a struct.
```

What are the rules when comparing a ValueType to null and how should I write the method to account for that without limiting the generic parameters by adding a class constraint?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Don't change the code - just ignore the warning. If the type parameter is a non-nullable value type, the comparison will always fail and it'll always call `ToString()` instead. I don't know whether it's actually JITted away, but I wouldn't be surprised... and this doesn't sound like it's performance-critical code anyway :)

I'd personally leave the warning "on", but ignore it in this particular case - possibly with a comment.

I think I came across the same warning a few times when reimplementing LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Since there's no way to compare a value type with null, there's no way to that the comparison won't be "JITted away". What else could the JITter do?

Comment: @Gabe: It could possibly call into some other code which will always return null. I'd hope not though.

Comment: I've added "//    I have Mr. Skeets express permission to ignore this warning." seems to do the trick :)

Comment: @panamack: Could I request an apostrophe in "Skeet's"? Ta.

Comment: certainly, "// I have Mr. Skeet(TODO add apostrophe here)s express permission to ignore this warning."

Comment: It's worth noting that if someone is truly bothered by the error message, they could always do `Object.ReferenceEquals(objA, null)` which is really just calling `objA == objB` in the .NET source code. And, I'm pretty sure that this will be JITted or inlined somehow. The nice thing is that the error message disappears though, and the call is still valid :)

Comment: For completeness, Eric Lippert [said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8824259/1083771) that the JIT does in fact replace a "val == null" check with "false" when compiling the method for a type parameter that's a non-nullable value type.

Comment: It seems like Resharper has dropped this warning. Can anyone confirm with official documentation?

Comment: @julealgon I'm still seeing this warning with ReSharper 2017.3.3

Comment: That's weird @Zero3. Now on our tools, only Sonarqube seems to complain about this. Are you sure your instance is the same as the one presented here and not another scenario?

Comment: @julealgon Good point. I just doublechecked by copy-pasting the code in the question, and ReSharper does indeed give me the warnings mentioned in the question. It is worth noting that this ReSharper inspection actually is disabled by default, which might be why you are not seeing it in your project.

Comment: Oh, this could definitely be why @Zero3. It's possible that it was once enabled by default, and was changed to disabled in newer versions. That would totally explain the behavior I saw across time on our projects here.

Comment: I just found that Dictionary implementation does comparisons generic-type variables with null. So we could call it MS standard :) and ignore these warnings. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,fd1acf96113fbda9,references

Answer (score 6):

> What are the rules when comparing a ValueType to null and how should I write the method to account for that without limiting the generic parameters by adding a class constraint?

If you do not know that they will be reference types, then you can say

```
private void AddMatchFailure<TExpected, TActual>(
    string failureName,
    TExpected expected,
    TActual actual
) {
    _matchFailures.Add(
        String.Format(MatchFailureFormat, failureName,
        IsDefault<TExpected>(expected) ? DefaultStringForType<TExpected>() : expected.ToString(),
        IsDefault<TActual>(actual) ? DefaultStringForType<TActual>() : actual.ToString()
    );
}

private bool IsDefault<T>(T value) {
    if(typeof(T).IsValueType) {
        return default(T).Equals(value);
    }
    else {
        return Object.Equals(null, value);
    }
}

private string DefaultStringForType<T>() {
    if(typeof(T).IsValueType) {
        return default(T).ToString();
    }
    else {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

Comment: But I think he wants to compare to `null`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: `default` of a reference type is `null`.

Comment: @Jason but it isn't `null` for a non nullable value type. It makes sense for the comparison to simply become a constant `false` for types without `null`. And that's probably the desired behavior for the OPs code.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: `default(Nullable<T>)` where `T` is a non-nullable value type is the instance of `Nullable<T>` where `Nullable<T>.HasValue` is `false` (i.e., it is `null`).

Comment: In my code, I simply want to never call null.ToString().  However, I also want my NUnit Constraint to be expressive when Matches() fails so thanks for reminding me how to use the default keyword with structs, I'd forgotten.

Comment: @Jason I know that, and that's unrelated to my objection to your code. Your `DefaultStringForType` doesn't handle a `Nullable<T>` that's `null` correctly. And even apart from that the OP's code is much cleaner than yours.

Comment: While this behaviour may sometimes be desired, it clearly isn't what the OP wants. It's clear he only seeks to prevent `NullReferenceExceptions` and use a `"null"` string instead. This code however  would print `0`, `false` or other default values, is more complicated, not intuitive and for what it's worth, also slower than a simple comparison with `null`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using something like this to check for null on generic types:

```
if (Equals(result, Default(T)))
```

Comment: Be careful! `default(int)` is 0, which can be a valid and explicitly set value. Checking for `default(T)` is quite different from checking for null.

Comment: +1 to @ANeves, resharper suggest this in there help page and to me it code smells http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Possible+compare+of+value+type+with+null

Comment: I also hate that example because it is clearly a case where most people would want `0.ToString()` to be called...

Answer (score -3):

```
private void AddMatchFailure<TExpected, TActual>(string failureName, TExpected expected, TActual actual)
{
    _matchFailures.Add(
        String.Format(MatchFailureFormat, failureName,
        (expected == default(TExpected)) ? "null" : expected.ToString(),
        (actual == default(TActual)) ? "null" : actual.ToString()));
}
```

Should do it.

`default(T)` gives the default value for that type, for reference types that's null - for others it depends. (Enums it's the equivalent of `(enumType)0` for example).

Comment: Then it will print "null" instead of 0 if you're comparing integers. Way to make a test failure hard to understand ;)

Comment: That gives me a compiler warning "Cannot apply operator == to operands of type 'TExpected' and 'TExpected'"

Comment: @Jon this is true, but it's the only way to get rid of the warning that fits the parameters. :p

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to get rid of the warning. It asks what to do about it :)

Comment: @Jon - fair enough... (now, where's the emoticon for "graciously concede")