# Comparing a generic against null that could be a value or reference type?

Tags: c#, generics, null, value-type, null-check

```
public void DoFoo<T>(T foo) where T : ISomeInterface<T>
{
    //possible compare of value type with 'null'.
    if (foo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
}
```

I'm purposely only checking against null because I don't want to restrict a `ValueType` from being equal to its `default(T)`. My code compiles and works just fine this way (ReSharper complains, but not CodeAnalysis). Though I do wonder:

- Is there a more *standard* way to handle this situation?
- Is there any chance of an issue arrising from this?
- What truly happens under the hood when I make a call and pass in a value type?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> I'm purposely only checking against `null` because I don't want to restrict a ValueType from being equal to its `default(T)`

That is a good insight, but don't worry, you are already covered there. It is not legal to compare a T against `default(T)` using `==` in the first place; overload resolution will not find a unique best `==` operator.

Of course, you could do the comparison with `.Equals` but then you run the risk of crashing if the receiver is null, which is precisely what you are attempting to avoid.

> Is there a more standard way to handle this situation?

No. Comparing to null is the right thing to do here.

As the C# specification says in section 7.10.6: "*The `x == null` construct is permitted even though T could represent a value type, and the result is simply defined to be false when T is a value type.*"

> Is there any chance of an issue arrising from this?

Sure. Just because code compiles does not mean that it has the semantics you intend. Write some tests.

> What truly happens under the hood when I make a call and pass in a value type?

The question is ambiguous. Let me rephrase it into two questions:

> What truly happens under the hood when I make a call on the generic method with a type argument that is a non-nullable value type?

The jitter compiles the method on the first invocation with that construction. When the jitter detects the null check, it replaces it with "false" because it knows that no non-nullable value type will ever be equal to null.

> What truly happens under the hood when I make a call on the generic method with a type argument that is a reference type but an argument that is a struct type? For example:

```
interface IFoo : ISomeInterface<IFoo> {}
struct SFoo : IFoo { whatever }
...
DoFooInternal<IFoo>(new SFoo());
```

In that case the jitter cannot elide the null check and the call site cannot avoid the boxing. The SFoo instance will be boxed, and the reference to the boxed SFoo will be checked to see if it is null.

Comment: It still confused me when `object.Equals(foo, default(T)))` where `foo` is a boxed value type returns `false` (e.g. `foo` is a `DateTime` but obtained via `PropertyInfo`'s `GetValue`).

Comment: Does the null check get optimized away for nullable value types or does the boxing happen in that case? Ideally it would convert to HasValue call, but from what I can tell empirically an == null check runs pretty slowly for nullable value types.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion: Good question -- which I should have covered in the original answer. I believe the jitter generates the code anew for nullable value types, and therefore can turn a null check into a call to HasValue rather than a box followed by a null check. Whether it actually does so, I do not remember. It should be fairly easy to check though; just write a little test program and look at the generated x86 code in the debugger.

Answer (score 11):

No, there won't be any problems, but if you want the warning to disappear, you can use the following:

```
public void DoFoo<T>(T foo) where T : ISomeInterface<T>
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(foo, null)) throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
}
```

Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
// when calling this with an actual T parameter, you have to either specify the type
// explicitly or cast the parameter to T?.
public void DoFoo<T>(T? foo) where T : struct, ISomeInterface<T>
{
    if (foo == null)
    {
        // throw...
    }

    DoFooInternal(foo.Value);
}

public void DoFoo<T>(T foo) where T : class, ISomeInterface<T>
{
    if (foo == null)
    {
        // throw...
    }

    DoFooInternal(foo); 
}

private void DoFooInternal<T>(T foo) where T : ISomeInterface<T>
{
    // actual implementation
}
```

Comment: Using `ReferenceEquals` will cause a boxing operation if `T` is a value-type, which may be undesirable.